# Select2 on hidden input on Modal does not have proper width

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm using select2 on a hidden input form element that's on a bootstrap 3 modal and for some reason the select2-default  will not fill the select2-container  completely and properly.

I can't upload a screenshot as I don't have reputation points.

Any ideas on how to resolve it?  I have tried to set the width on the input element and it still does not work. Is it perhaps because I had to append the modal to the document body because the modal is generated using ajax?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!